# Doctrine generate/symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hello I have a concern I learn symfony and I get this error when I try to generate doctrine. I look on google but no solutions helped me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It would be a lot better if you used the StackOverflow formatter instead of posting a screenshot indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might have misconfigured Doctrine's DB connection parameters. Double-check your `parameters.yml`'s `database_*` options and make sure these are valid for your database.

Also, perhaps you could be a bit more specific in the question: what command did you run, exactly?

Comment: Thank you I did not have the database creates the basis of the fact that I was using.

Comment: @delou, if the answer has helped you, do you mind accepting it?